# ASP.net OWIN OAuth middleware with bearer token and changing roles

Tags: asp.net, oauth, owin, bearer-token

I am using the standard ASP.net OWIN OAuth middleware system to authenticate local users with Bearer tokens. I was thinking of embedding roles as a claim in the token, but was wondering how I would be able to change a users role such as taking away admin privileges without them logging out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's always possible to implement some dirty solutions to support your problem, for example :
When the roles have changed then raise an even in a queue like RABBITMQ / NServiceBus (or via event). 
The subscriber (website) will invalidate the cookie and regenerate a new one with new claims.

I don't see the issue with waiting for the cookie is expired. 
In fact a bearer token (identity or access) has an "expires_in" property, so even if your cookie
is regenerated with new claims, the token is still valid in the provider.
Another remark your permissions can be returned by a UMA server, they shouldn't necessarily comes from your claims.
Take a look to this scenario : http://lokit.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/Documentation#third-scenario-limit-access-to-certain-website-features